# Gantt Chart Style Change for 2016

Tags: ms-project-2016

I have just changed over to MS Project 2016 Pro from 2010 and have noticed that the Gantt Style is different. The better aesthetic look of the rounded bars and shading in 2010 has gone in 2016.

Does anyone know how I can get them in 2016.

Thanks,

Michael Childs

Answer (score 2):

You can't.  The 3d bars went away with the introduction of MSP 2013; it's not an option.  If 3d bars are really important to you, then you could "downgrade" back to MSP 2010, or try to make pretty charts in Visio.